# How can I improve the learning of FCN32 for semantic segmentation?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, deeplearning4j

I have trained [FCN32](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org) for semantic segmentation from scratch for my data, and I got the following output:
[image]

As it can be seen, this is not a good learning curve showing an improper training on data. 
`solver` is as follows:

```
net: "train_val.prototxt"
#test_net: "val.prototxt"
test_iter: 5105 #736
# make test net, but don't invoke it from the solver itself
test_interval: 1000000 #20000
display: 50
average_loss: 50
lr_policy: "step" #"fixed"
stepsize: 50000 #+
gamma: 0.1  #+
# lr for unnormalized softmax
base_lr: 1e-10 
# high momentum
momentum: 0.99
# no gradient accumulation
iter_size: 1
max_iter: 600000
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 30000
snapshot_prefix: "snapshot/FCN32s_CNN1"
test_initialization: false
solver_mode: GPU
```

after changing the learning rate to 0.001, it became worse:
[image]
I am wondering what can I do for improving the training? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try varying the learning rate. Good values are normally something between 0.1 and 0.0001.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I edited the question, when I set the learning rate to 0.001, the learning curve becomes worse.

Comment: The loss is actually better number wise.  But your learning rate seems too high now.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your suggestion